# How to create mysql table with column timestamp default current_date?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp, create-table

I need to create mysql table with default value on column CURRENT_DATE()

I try

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `visitors`;
CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `browser` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `version` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `platform` ENUM('w','l','m') NOT NULL,
  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `person` (`ip`,`date`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

but it is writting an error

```
Query: CREATE TABLE `visitors` ( `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `ip` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, `browser` VARCHAR(500) NO...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE() NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `person` (`ip`,`date`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 7

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.063 sec
```

what is the problem?

I need to uniques only date 
not with full time info...

can you help me?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of a `TIMESTAMP` column.  You don't actually need to specify `DEFAULT` in this case.

Comment: TIMESTAMP and DATE do not have the same format, Timestamp is a number while date is a formatted date. Choose one or the other.

Comment: Why don't you try `'date' DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE()` if you only need year, month and day.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** function instead of **CURRENT_DATE()** function

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `visitors`;
CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `browser` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `version` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `platform` ENUM('w','l','m') NOT NULL,
  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `person` (`ip`,`date`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: no CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is setting full time informations with hour,minutes and secunds too.  I need only year,month and day

Comment: One option is to set it up as a timestamp, as shown, but when you actually retrieve the data, just cast it as a date, which will truncate the hours, minutes and seconds.  `SELECT DATE(`date`)` will return it in the format you appear to want, while still preserving the behavior you want for the column.

Comment: I understand but I need to unique IP with year, month and date
so if I unique it as timestamp
after 2-3 second ago it will insert again new row...
I need unique becouse
after refresh if IP is exists today it must not write in table

so becouse I need only date format

Answer (score 0):

you just have to replace CURRENT_DATE() by NOW() in your query.
I tried it and it's look ok.

Comment: NOW() will be consider as `CURRENT_TIMESTMAP` in mysql

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late but I think it might be helpful to someone else.

My approach has been to use getdate() like this:

[TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_myTable_TimeStamp]  DEFAULT (getdate()).

***Where [TimeStamp] is the column in question.***

*The result is for example: 2017-11-02 11:58:34.203*

To trim this, I use the following

declare @mydate datetime

set @mydate = '2017-11-02 11:58:34.203'

SELECT try_convert(nvarchar(20), @mydate, 120)

This final result is: **2017-11-02 11:58:34**

[You can actually set this in MSSQL Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kolcp.png)