# What is MySQL TIMESTAMP in PHP @property datatype?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL Data called last_seen and its datatype is TIMESTAMP, should I save it as a String in PHP?

```
 * @property boolean                                  verified_address
 * @property boolean                                  verified_email
 * @property string                                   last_seen
```

Comment: no need to store anything,it will update the current datetime automatically whenever a transaction is made

Comment: nope, never ever store date,time, dateTime, Timestamp into string.

Comment: @SaadSuri so what datatype should i store it in?

Comment: Timestamp is fine for last_seen.

Comment: @Deepak so you're saying just remove "@property string"?

Comment: @SaadSuri "@property Timestamp"?

Comment: I think it's a comment of a docBlocker check your db structure what datatype you're using.

Comment: @SaadSuri I saved it as $table->timestamp in my db structure

Comment: then leave it as it is. it will be automatically updated

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418077/how-to-create-mysql-table-with-column-timestamp-default-current-date

Comment: @SaadSuri Alright, I'll just leave it as "@property string" , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since TIMESTAMP isn't a php  data type, you have to use 'mixed' for the @property.

In the documentation you have examples for diferent data types (https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html)

For your case it would be like this

```php
/**
 * @property boolean  verified_address
 * @property boolean  verified_email
 * @property mixed    $last_seen
*/
```