# Select total hours of first-in and last out in 1 day. then total hours in next day should count. to sum total hours in multiple days

Tags: mysql, xampp

How to code a query i need to show total hours of one day from first-in to last-out. then total hours for next day.

For example I in (2022-02-01 07:39:12) then i out 2022-02-01 19:39:12 So its 13. hrs in 1 day.

Then next day in  2022-02-02 09:00:12, out 2022-02-02 19:00:12 12 and its 11 hrs.

So Total hours would be 24hrs.

```
[EmployeeID]   [Att_Date]
 11            2022-02-01 07:39:12
 11            2022-02-01 19:39:12
 11            2022-02-02 09:00:12
 11            2022-02-02 19:00:12
 33            2022-02-03 08:00:12
 33            2022-02-03 19:00:12
 33            2022-02-04 08:00:12
 33            2022-02-04 19:39:12...
```

I tried this code below but wrong result, it just minus/subract from first-in of day 1 to last in of day 2.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, MIN(Att_Date),MAX(Att_Date)) AS Total_Hours
FROM att_details 
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

[image]

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: hi raju, i wish to clarify, do you wanted the hours each day attended for every day or entire sum of the hours for given employee id?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`group by` against two column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418077/how-to-create-mysql-table-with-column-timestamp-default-current-date), as such you can weave your query to calculate the daily hours as such:

```
 select EmployeeID,
         date(Att_Date) as Date,
         timestampdiff(hour, min(att_date), max(att_date)) as Total_Hours
      from att_details
      group by EmployeeID, date(Att_Date)
```

With the following input:

```
 +------------+---------------------+
 | EmployeeID | Att_Date            |
 +------------+---------------------+
 | 11         | 2022-02-01 07:39:12 |
 +------------+---------------------+
 | 11         | 2022-02-01 19:39:12 |
 +------------+---------------------+
 | 11         | 2022-02-02 09:00:12 |
 +------------+---------------------+
 | 11         | 2022-02-02 19:00:12 |
 +------------+---------------------+
 | 33         | 2022-02-03 08:00:12 |
 +------------+---------------------+
 | 33         | 2022-02-03 19:00:12 |
 +------------+---------------------+
 | 33         | 2022-02-04 08:00:12 |
 +------------+---------------------+
 | 33         | 2022-02-04 19:39:12 |
 +------------+---------------------+
```

It should output:

```
 +------------+------------+-------------+
 | EmployeeID | Date       | Total_Hours |
 +------------+------------+-------------+
 | 11         | 2022-02-01 | 12          |
 +------------+------------+-------------+
 | 11         | 2022-02-02 | 10          |
 +------------+------------+-------------+
 | 33         | 2022-02-03 | 11          |
 +------------+------------+-------------+
 | 33         | 2022-02-04 | 11          |
 +------------+------------+-------------+
```

Then you could aggregate daily hours of each employee ID using the query above as source for the `SUM` operation as such:

```
 select t.EmployeeID,
        SUM(t.Total_Hours) as Total_Hours
     from
   (select EmployeeID,
           date(Att_Date) as Date,
           timestampdiff(hour, min(att_date), max(att_date)) as Total_Hours
        from att_details
        group by EmployeeID, date(Att_Date)) as t
     group by t.EmployeeID
```

It should output the following:

```
 +------------+-------------+
 | EmployeeID | Total_Hours |
 +------------+-------------+
 | 11         | 22          |
 +------------+-------------+
 | 33         | 22          |
 +------------+-------------+
```

I have tested the query on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pn4TScCdsYjUwaur6CDCNB/0), hope it helps.

Note:

- You can remove the `date(Att_Date) as Date` given it only serve the purpose to show how it separates each day.
- It doesn't account for case when someone checks out at the next day